# Reproduce some website ideas on my own opensource project

Tags: internet, open-source-software, france

I am a developer and I recently came accross a website to practice my development environment skills. This website has a premium access policy and rather than paying, I would like to develop my own project to reproduce some of their ideas, to practise on my own.

I think that I can legally do that at home without risking any kind of legal attacks.

However, I would also like to share my code on [GitHub](https://github.com/), to make it available for other people, and have a bit more visibility for future potential employers.

Since I won't be using any of the code of the proprietary website, Is opensourcing my code illegal ? I won't copying the website exactly but take some of its ideas.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What exactly are "some of their ideas"? What ideas are you "taking"? Site designs? Site features and functions?

Comment: I plan to take only features, no design. What do you mean by "site functions" ? Actual code or another thing ?

Comment: What is an example of a "feature" you will take?

Comment: The application has a screen where you type keyboard shortcuts to exercise. You can decide to show, hide, or show with a delay the shortcut. It telles you if you're wrong when you type it ... You can fight with an AI to see who's the fastest ... There are other features but those are the ones I'd like to reproduce for now. Hope this helps ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fine. You can pretty much take any idea/feature that the site has and implement it yourself. The whole internet is based of taking an idea or feature somebody else had and improving upon it. Just don't copy the code like you said.

No opensourcing your code is not illegal but there are a few different types of licenses.